# How did the Stellar Blockchain Network start?

Tags: nodes, network

Based on some searches I learned that Stellar was created by Jed McCaleb in 2014, does anyone know how did he start the network? I do not see any information regarding this online, can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Dunno if that's helpful, here's something I wrote 1.5 years ago
https://galactictalk.org/d/230-history-of-stellar-as-i-remember-it

Comment: The article ends by saying "In November 2015 new network has been launched. And development continues since.", the article is written well but I am trying to find how did he start the network. If possible, could you please direct me to some resources where I might get this information.

Comment: What specifics are you looking for? "How did he start the network" can mean a lot of different things to different people

Comment: by that I meant, how did Jed McCaleb, start the stellar blockchain network?

Comment: If you're looking for technical specifics how to start network using stellar software, then this might help you https://www.stellar.org/developers/stellar-core/software/testnet.html 
Jed essentially did the same, chose passphrase for the network, started few nodes and boom.
If that's not helpful, then I don't know what you're looking for